# InputEvent cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

So, whenever I run the program below it says "InputEvent cannot be resolved to a variable". Can you help me to fix this problem?
Heres's the code ->

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
public class RobotExp4{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        try{
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            System.out.println("3 Seconds after this message appears the robot will click");
            robot.delay(3000);
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.delay(75);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the necessary `import` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the import statement for that class.

Simply add `import java.awt.event.InputEvent;` at the top of your source code.